# Foundation.Date turns to nil after returning from function

Tags: ios, swift, date, tuples

I have some decoders for different types.
In this function decoders for date are creating.

```
private static var __once: () = {
//possible formats
    let formatters = [
        "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    ].map { (format: String) -> DateFormatter in
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        return formatter
    }
    // Decoder for Date
    Decoders.addDecoder(clazz: Date.self) { (source: AnyObject, instance: AnyObject?) -> Decoded<Date> in
       if let sourceString = source as? String {
            for formatter in formatters {
                if let date = formatter.date(from: sourceString) {
                    return .success(date) //in this state date = 2022-03-26 05:45:00 +0000 (not nil)
                }
            }
        }
        ...some code
    }
```

Decoder calls here. It work right way for another types, but "date" turns to nil after returning from decoder function.

```
static func decodeOptional<T>(clazz: T.Type, source: AnyObject?) -> Decoded<T?> {
    if let source = source, !(source is NSNull) {
        switch Decoders.decode(clazz: clazz, source: source, instance: nil) { //this function call decoder for date from above. 
        case let .success(value): return .success(value) // but date in this statement turns no nil
        case let .failure(error): return .failure(error)
        }
    } else {
        return .success(nil)
    }
}

static func decode<T>(clazz: T.Type, source: AnyObject, instance: AnyObject?) -> Decoded<T> {
    initialize()
    ...somecode...//decoder with key "Date"
    let key = "\(T.self)"
    if let decoder = decoders[key], let value = decoder(source, instance) as? Decoded<T> {
       return value
    } else {
        return .failure(.typeMismatch(expected: String(describing: clazz), actual: String(describing: source)))
    }
}
```

Returning type:

```
public enum Decoded<ValueType> { ////ValueType = Date
 case success(ValueType)
 case failure(DecodeError)
}
```

Why Date object turns from real value to nil after returning from function?

Comment: Returning type:

public enum Decoded<ValueType> {
    case success(ValueType)
    case failure(DecodeError)
}

//ValueType = Date

Comment: Your code isn't complete and somewhat hard to understand but isn't `return .success(date) ` called from inside a closure but the returned value is ignored? And don't post additional info in the comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` doesnt make any sense if the timezone is coming in the date string

Comment: Note also that you are not specifying a Calendar. Your date formatter will use the devices calendar which can lead to years with more than 2 thousand years offset.

Comment: with timeZone or not, results are same

Comment: Note also that escaping the Z that comes from the string is wrong. Z means UTC timezone. You are supposed to parse it not ignore it

Comment: Well I never said this would solve your issue

Comment: Note also that `AnyObject` is for objects not structures. You should use `Any`

Comment: Thx, i will try to use your recommendations